# Dynamically import a remote ES module from an URL, in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webpack, es6-modules, observablehq

I'm playing around with [Observable notebooks](https://observablehq.com/) and loving it. Now I want to embed a notebook on my web app. Using vanilla Javascript and Javascript modules this works well:

```js
<script type="module">
  import {Runtime, Inspector} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@4/dist/runtime.js";
  import notebook from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3";
  new Runtime().module(notebook, Inspector.into(document.body));
</script>
```

When I attemt to import a module through a remote URL in TypeScript, I get compile errors:

```js
// error: Cannot find module 'https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3'
import notebook from 'https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3';
```

I've tried ignoring the compile-time errors using `// @ts-ignore`, but then they occur at runtime. I'm also looking into the [import-http](https://github.com/egoist/import-http) Webpack plugin, but that still does not appear to solve the compile-time errors.

I fully understand this is not specific to Obervable, but more related to TypeScript and/or Webpack. However, alternatives specific to Observable would be appreciated as well.

So, my question is: How can I **dynamically** import a remote/external ES module, in TypeScript? This so I can reproduce something like:

```js
// url = 'https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3';

public async foo(url: string): Promise<void> {
  const notebook = await import(url);

  const runtime = new Runtime();
  const main = runtime.module(notebook, Inspector.into(document.body));
}
```

Comment: have you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: you need to declare module and include it in `tsconfig.json`

I think it's because typescript can't find any definition about this module

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479432/ts-cannot-find-modules) and this [document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html) could help you.

I did create a sample project to test this.

```
.
└── ./
    ├── src/
    │   ├── declarations.d.ts
    │   └── index.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

```
// index.ts
import notebook from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3";
```

```
// declarations.d.ts
// either
declare module 'https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3'

// or
declare module "https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3" {}

// or
declare module "https://api.observablehq.com/d/d64beea6bedb0375.js?v=3" {
  export default function define(runtime:any, observer:any):any
}
```

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ....your config
  },
  "include": [
    ....your config
    "./src/declarations.d.ts" // add this line
  ]
}
```